# What word describes the act of convincing someone to buy you a meal or drink?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, dictionaries

The context of this question is as followed: I was in a meeting where two people had placed a bet on the outcome of an event. The deal was that the loser would buy the winner a drink.  As they were discussing the possibilities of different outcomes, one said to another "don't worry I am only trying to ..... a drink from you.
I didn't know what the meaning of that word so I quickly googled it but didn't write down its definition. Does anyone here know what word best describes the act of getting someone buy you/treat you to a drink/meal etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **Rista** suggestion, I checked the thesaurus for similar words to mooch where I came across the word I was searching.

The word was **Scrounge**.

Answer (score 5):

How about this one? This one seems quite popular.

"don't worry I am only trying **to mooch a drink off you**".